# Clipping and dynamic resizing

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have a container with a vertical layout inside which I have two other child containers "A" and "B".  
 
In the first container "A" there is a component that I would like to resize dynamically based on the available display size. 
 To to that I tried listening  to the resize event of the main container and do my measures accordingly. 
 That works somewhat until the parent container reaches a clipping size : container "B" gets clipped earlier than "A" because it contains much more stuffs : 
 As soon as the parent container reaches "B"'s clipping size, it does not resize anymore (so no more resize event either) thus preventing me from updating my component's display in "A".

Any directions would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got something like this (correct me, if I'm wrong):

```
<mx:VBox>
    <mx:VBox id="A" width="100%" height="100%">
        <CustomComponent id="component" width="100%" height="100%"/>
    </mx:VBox>
    <mx:VBox id="B"/>
</mx:VBox>
```

You don't need to listen to resize events, Flex containers can resize automatically. Your resize layout behavior is reached by assigning proper size in percents for container A and your component. Here you have container A, which occupies all the free space provided by its parent - top container. Therefore your inner component occupies all the free space provided by its parent - component A. When top container resizes, its children will automatically resize themselves.

In pure ActionScript the corresponding properties are `percentHeight` and `percentWidth`.

**UPD**

1) The problem with size of B is solved by adding `minWidth="10"` (or 0, or min size you want). That forces B to resize with parent container, even if there's not enough space in parent.

2) If you want to do some different layout in you custom component, or to make some calculations, based on new component size, you should override function "updateDisplayeList" in your custom component:

```
override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledHeight:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
{
    super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

    // your calculations
}
```

This function is called by Flex `layoutManager`, when the component needs to refresh its size and/or children positions. The arguments represent available space for component.

More on Flex component lifecycle:

- http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ascomponents_advanced_2.html
- (strongly recommend) http://www.developmentarc.com/site/articles

3) Some sort of offtop.

I've got a feeling, that you simply have `VBox` of `Labels`, and these `Labels` don't want to resize with its parent. This problem is solved by assigning some small value to Labels's `minWidth` - after that `Labels` will be correctly truncated if they exceed parent size.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to oversimplify the problem in my explanation. Actually, I need to change not only the size of the component but also do some text truncation depending on the available size.

Comment: Also, I'm already doing the above but when the container reaches the limit size of B, it won't resize anymore, so A will just get clipped event if it can still resize.

Comment: Thanks, you got me on the right track. Actually I'm adding new screens to an existing application and it so happens that the top level container's minWidth was set so everytime I reach it, my subcontainers won't resize anymore and just clips their children. The child component will call it's updateDisplayList so long as itself can resize. Once it gets clipped nothing happens. As I cannot remove the minWidth of the application, I ended up listening to the stage resize event to check if some clipping occurs on the component.